# Passing an image from oneview to anohter view in IOS

Tags: ios

I am having a Table with 10 rows and an Images and two labels in Each cell.  I want to display the image in a full screen view in other view when user taps on it. Can you help me in that?

Answer (score 1):

create a property of UIImage in the viewController.h where you want to display big image, and synthesise the object in viewController.m file.

Now on didselectRowAtIndexPath method create a instance of the view controller and assign the object to UIImage view property created with a  "." operator.

ViewController.h file write the below code:

```
@property(assign,nonatomic) UIImage *image;
```

ViewController.m file write the below code :

```
@synthesize image;
```

TableViewController.m file write below code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method :

```
ViewController *vc = [[[ViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
vc.image = someImage;
[self.navigationController pushToViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

for that you have to decalre UIImageView property in second view like below and synthesize it

```
@interface secondViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageToMove;
@end

@implementation secondViewController

@synthesize imageToMove;

.....

@end
```

now you can access it in your second view by assigning it in first view like below

```
firstViewController *firstView = [[[firstViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
firstView.imageToMove = someImage;
[self.navigationController pushToViewController:firstView animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

In `didSelectRowAtIndex`: get the image of the row and add it to what ever view you want to.

Answer (score 0):

First create an imageview in second view controller

```
ImageShowViewcontroller.h

@interface ImageShowViewcontroller ()
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *SecondViewImageView;
@end
```

in .m You can synthesize it like below

```
ImageShowViewcontroller.m

@implementation ImageShowViewcontroller

@synthesize SecondViewImageView;
```

in FirstView.m  in didselectRow() function you can pass the image to ImageShowViewcontroller class like below

FirstView.m

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ImageShowViewcontroller *ImagePass = [[ImageShowViewcontroller alloc]init];

    ImagePass.SecondViewImageView.image=cell.imageView.image;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ImageShowViewcontroller animated:NO];


}
```

In cell.image your pressed row image will be avilable and it will be passed to next view SecondViewImageView throw object of second class. If i did any mistake pls let me know it